# Find limit of sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-product

I suspect that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n  - 1}\frac{k}{a^k(n - k)} = 0$ for $a > 1$. I know that this product represents the taylor coefficients of $\frac{-ax\ln(1 - x)}{(a - x)^2}$ by the Cauchy product. Unfortunately the limit as $x \to 1^{-1}$ is not defined so I can't use Abel's theorem. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is zero as expected. First, write the sum as

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k}{a^k(n-k)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{a^k(n-k)} \mathbf{1}_{\{k < n\}}$$

Since each term is uniformly bounded by

$$ \left| \frac{k}{a^k(n-k)}\mathbf{1}_{\{k < n\}} \right| \leq \frac{k}{a^k} $$

and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{a^k} < \infty$, the [*dominated convergence theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) tells that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{a^k(n-k)} \mathbf{1}_{\{k < n\}} 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{k}{a^k(n-k)} \mathbf{1}_{\{k < n\}}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 0 = 0. $$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The limit is zero. The following is an elementary
proof.

Write $\beta=a-1>0$. Then $a^{k}=(1+\beta)^{k}\geq\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\beta^{2}\geq\frac{k^{2}}{4}\beta^{2}$
for $k\geq2$. Now 
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{k}{a^{k}(n-k)}\leq\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{4}{k^{2}\beta^{2}}\cdot\frac{k}{(n-k)}=\frac{4}{\beta^{2}}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}.
$$
Observe that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right)=\frac{2S_{n}}{n},
$$
where $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$. Note that 
$$
S_{n}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\leq1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{1}{x}dx\leq1+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x}=1+\ln n.
$$
By squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2S_{n}}{n}=0$. 
Hence, by squeeze theorem again, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{a^{k}(n-k)}=0$ .

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\left.\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
> {k \over a^{k}\pars{n - k}}\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1} = 0:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\left.\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
{k \over a^{k}\pars{n - k}}\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{k \over a^{k}\pars{n - k}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{n - k \over a^{n - k}\,k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
{n \over a^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{a^{k} \over k} -
{1 \over a^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}a^{k}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
{n \over a^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{a^{k} \over k} -
{1 \over a^{n}}\,a\,{a^{n - 1} - 1 \over a - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{{n \over a^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{a^{k} \over k}}} -
{1 - a^{1 - n} \over a - 1}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] &
\bbx{\mbox{Note that}\quad
\left.\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 - a^{1 - n} \over a - 1}
\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1} = {1 \over a - 1}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{{n \over a^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{a^{k} \over k}}} & =
{n \over a^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}a^{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\,\dd t =
{n \over a^{n - 1}}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\pars{at}^{k - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{n \over a^{n - 1}}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{at}^{n - 1} - 1 \over at - 1}\,\dd t =
{n \over a^{n}}\int_{0}^{a}{t^{n - 1} - 1 \over t - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{n \over a^{n}}\int_{0}^{a}{\pars{a - t}^{n - 1} - 1 \over
\pars{a - t} - 1}\,\dd t =
{n \over a^{n}}\int_{0}^{a}{\exp\pars{\ln\pars{\pars{a - t}^{n - 1} - 1}} \over
\pars{a - t} - 1}\,\dd t\label{3}\tag{3}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&\
{n \over a^{n}}\pars{a^{n - 1} - 1}\,
{a^{n - 1} - 1 \over a^{n - 2}\pars{n - 1}}\,{1 \over a - 1}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\large\to}\,\,\,\bbx{1 \over a - 1}
\label{4}\tag{4}
\end{align}

> \eqref{3} evaluation involves the application of the
>   [Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).

Finally, with \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} and \eqref{4}:
$$
\bbx{\left.\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
{k \over a^{k}\pars{n - k}}\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1} = 0}
$$

Answer (score -1):

[Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem#Remarks) remarks says that as
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, \frac{-a x \log (1-x)}{(a-x)^2}=+\infty;\;a>1$$
then the series of coefficients diverges to $\infty$ therefore, according to some experiment I made with *Mathematica*, the series diverges

Comment: This result tells us that $\sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{k}{a^k(n - k)}$ diverges, which tells us nothing about whether the terms go to 0.